# Unknown Visualforce Error CompositeFont

Tags: apex, visualforce, getcontentaspdf

I am getting an exception like below-

***System.VisualforceException: class sun.font.CompositeFont cannot be cast to class sun.font.PhysicalFont (sun.font.CompositeFont and sun.font.PhysicalFont are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')***

My Visualforce line is

```
<tr><td colspan="4" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  text-align: center; font-size:30px; color:#231f20; font-weight:700;  margin:0px; background: ##FFFF00;">&nbsp;<Strike><apex:outputPanel >{!JobSale}</apex:outputPanel></Strike>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><span style="background: yellow;font-size:35px;">{!DiscountedAmount}</span></b></td>
```

And Apex lines are-

```
upchargediscounttotaljobsales=opp[0].PRODQuoteupchargeDiscountTotalJobSale__c;  //-----------This is the Discount + Upcharge Amount
    //TotalJobSale = opp.get(0).Total_Job_Sale__c;
    upchargeValue = String.valueOf(opp[0].PRODQuoteUpchargeValue__c);
    upchargeValue = upchargeValue.replace(',', '');  //-----------------------This is the Upcharge Amount
    JobDecimal = opp[0].ProdQuoteBaseplusUpcharge__c;
    JobDecimal = JobDecimal.replace(',','');
    TotalJobSale = Decimal.valueOf(JobDecimal);  //---------------------------This is the Total Amount + Upcharge(If Any)
    Discount = opp.get(0).PRODQuoteDiscountValue__c;
    Discount = Discount.replace(',', '');       //----------------------------This is the Discount Amount

    System.debug('Raw value of Upcharge: '+upchargeValue);
    System.debug('Raw value of Discount: '+Discount);
    system.debug('Decimal value of Discount: ' +decimal.valueOf(Discount));
    system.debug('Incoming Total Job Sale: '+TotalJobSale);

    //*** When Discount = 0 && Upcharge = 0 ***/
    if((Discount == '' || Discount == null || Discount =='0.0' || Discount =='0') && (upchargeValue == '' || upchargeValue == null || upchargeValue =='0.0' || upchargeValue =='0'))
    {
        system.debug('In If');
        JobSale = '';
        DiscountedAmount = 'Only $'+opp[0].PRODQuoteupchargeDiscountTotalJobSale__c;
    }

    //*** When Discount != 0 && Upcharge = 0 ***/
    else if((Discount != '' || Discount != null || Discount !='0.0' || Discount !='0') && (upchargeValue == '' || upchargeValue == null || upchargeValue =='0.0' || upchargeValue =='0'))
    {
        if(decimal.valueOf(Discount) < TotalJobSale)
        {
            system.debug('In Else-If1');
            DiscountedAmount = 'Only $'+opp[0].PRODQuoteupchargeDiscountTotalJobSale__c;
            system.debug('Discounted Amount: '+DiscountedAmount);

            JobSale = '$'+(TotalJobSale.format().contains('.')?TotalJobSale.format():(TotalJobSale.format()+'.00'));
            system.debug('Total Job Sale: ' +JobSale);
        }
        else if(decimal.valueOf(Discount) == TotalJobSale)
        {
            system.debug('In Else-If2');
            DiscountedAmount = '';
            JobSale = '';
        }
    }
    //*** When Discount == 0 && Upcharge != 0 ***/
    else if((Discount == '' || Discount == null || Discount =='0.0' || Discount =='0') && (upchargeValue != '' || upchargeValue != null || upchargeValue !='0.0' || upchargeValue !='0'))
    {
        DiscountedAmount = 'Only $'+opp[0].PRODQuoteupchargeDiscountTotalJobSale__c;
        JobSale = '';
    }

    //*** When Discount != 0 && Upcharge != 0 ***/
    else if((Discount != '' || Discount != null || Discount !='0.0' || Discount !='0') && (upchargeValue != '' || upchargeValue != null || upchargeValue !='0.0' || upchargeValue !='0'))
    {
        DiscountedAmount = 'Only $'+opp[0].PRODQuoteupchargeDiscountTotalJobSale__c;
        JobSale = '$'+(TotalJobSale.format().contains('.')?TotalJobSale.format():(TotalJobSale.format()+'.00'));
    }
```

I didn't get any error on Developer console. But when I am running my application, I got the above exception. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the font in the in-line CSS ?

"style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"

Or recompiling the Apex class since that may be a java bug.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144703

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for your reply. I removed "style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;" from CSS. But unfortunately still facing the same error.

Comment: I have seen a similar issue, and I see that removing the CSS was not the solution, so, did it the recompile all classes worked?